# Implementing GetBSDProcessList from sysctl.h

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, macos, process

Could someone give me some advice or a snippet of code that would show me the way of implementing the method [in this listing](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html) . I would like to get some info about processes on a mac. I'm not so good with C, but am familiar with Objective C.

Thanks!

Comment: You can just compile this code "as is" and link it with your Objective-C code - no need to re-implement it.

Comment: and if I wanted to print a list of processes for example? How would I do that?

Comment: Eric Brotto: Call that function, then iterate over the list it returned and print the `p_comm` (command name) member of each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer on cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/92971-bsd-processes-with-code.html) which is a good start, but it could use some expanding.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific about you what you want to do above and beyond that example code.